# How do I display values under the cursor in the second form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

[image]
I draw a candlestick chart from the file data.

Create a new form(second form) when you click the button in which you want to display:
time, high, low, open, close.

```
namespace stock5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.CandleStick_Load);
        }

        private void CandleStick_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CHART();
        }

        public void CHART()
        {
             *************************************************
            //The code reads the data from the file is skipped.

            chart1.Series.Clear();
            Series price = new Series("price");
            chart1.Series.Add(price);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;
            chart1.Series["price"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Candlestick;
            chart1.Series["price"]["OpenCloseStyle"] = "Triangle";
            chart1.Series["price"]["ShowOpenClose"] = "Both";
            chart1.Series["price"]["PointWidth"] = "2.0";
            chart1.Series["price"]["PriceUpColor"] = "Blue"; 
            chart1.Series["price"]["PriceDownColor"] = "Red";
            chart1.Series["price"].BorderColor = Color.Black;
            chart1.Series["price"]["MaxPixelPointWidth"] = "2.0";

            for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
            {
                chart1.Series["price"].Points.AddXY(index[i], mass[i, 1], mass[i, 2], mass[i, 0], mass[i, 3]);//index, high, low, open, close
            }

            int INDEX = 0;
            foreach (DataPoint point in chart1.Series["price"].Points)
            {
                point.AxisLabel = nums[INDEX].ToString();//Replacing the index values for the time(To avoid empty values when markets are closed on weekends)
                INDEX++;
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

The second form in which you want to print values depending on the location of the cursor.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form newForm = new Form();
            newForm.Show();
            newForm.Width = 170;
            newForm.Height = 230;
        }
```

And a passing question: how to get instead of indexes in the form of time?

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways you can communicate with first form in time and here is one of it:

I assume your `Form` is your new form? (I will use it in my example as it is)

For this example i will create custom class (object) which i will be returning to newly created form every 0.2 sec.

So new object would be

```
public class MyNewObject
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Speed { get; set; }
}
```

So class of `Form` will look like this (at least code which is needed to perform this)

```
public partial class Form : Form
{
    Timer t = new Timer();
    private YourFirstForm myFirstForm;

    public Form(YourFirstForm form)
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        myFirstForm = form;

        t.Interval = 200; //0.2 sec 

        Thread t1 = new Thread(FirstFormListener);
        t1.Start();
    }

    private void FirstFormListner()
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 200; //0.2 sec

        t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick); 
        t.Enabled = true; 
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyNewObject someData = myFirstForm.GetSomeData();
        MessageBox.Show(someData.Name);
    }
}
```

And inside your first form:

```
public partial class YourFirstForm : Form
{
    string someString = "Some random string";

    public YourFirstForm()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    public MyNewObject GetSomeData()
    {
        MyNewObject mno = new MyNewObject();
        mno.Name = "Random name";
        mno.Id = 1;
        mno.Speed = 200;
        return mno;
    }
}
```

This is one way of doing it and i think it is practical since you can adjust interval of thick so set update time (on slower pc set it to lower value for faster you can to faster value). Also updating is done on separate thread so it doesn't affect your UI (freeze) and you can continue with job.

Comment: Wrote below in a separate message.
Got the value in the second form.
I can't go any further.